# Set default value on a dropdown depending on another ones value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm struggling with **Reactive forms**, I have a cascading dropdown which can have a default value if the user selected an existing project in the first page ( issue is in this page ), if the user wants to create a project then the dropdown does not render any value.

So here's the issue :

When the user comes **from an existing project** the pricelist is selected but it seems that it doesn't have any value cause the currency isn't shown. When I select again the pricelist the currency's auto-selected as expected, anyone have a fix for this ? Thank's in advance.

[image]

Here's the code sample, thank you for your time

**JSON** (returned from *pageChanged()*)

[image]

**Component.ts** (auto select values)

```
  pageChanged(event){
const current = this.currentPage = event;
return this.httpClient.get<QuotationsInterface>(`this.url${this.projectId}?page=${current}&token=${this.token.token}`)
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log('GET PROJECT BY ID OK',data);
      this.project = data.project;
      this.registerForm.controls['pricelist'].setValue(this.project.pricelist_id);
      this.registerForm.controls['currency'].setValue(this.project.currency_id);
    },
    error => {
      console.log("PAGE PROJECT FAILED", error)
    }
  )
```

}

**Component.html**

```
<div class="flex2 pl10" (change)="selectedPriceListIndex = $event.target.selectedIndex-1">
  <select formControlName="pricelist" class="form-control"  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && f.pricelist.errors}" >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Pricelist</option>
    <option   *ngFor="let p of filter.ListPricelist;let i = index;" [ngValue]="p.id"  id="pricelist_id" >{{i}} {{p.label}}</option>
  </select>
  <div *ngIf="submitted && f.pricelist.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="f.pricelist.errors.required">Pricelist is required</div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="flex2 pl10">
  <select formControlName="currency" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && f.currency.errors}" class="form-control">
    <option value >Select a currency</option>
    <option  *ngFor="let c of filter.ListPricelist[selectedPriceListIndex]?.currencies" [ngValue]="c.id" selected="selected">{{c.code}}</option>
  </select>
    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.currency.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="f.currency.errors.required">Currency is required</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**EDIT :**

Thank's to everyone answers I made it work by using **.patchValue** ( check @nima_amr answer ) and also by replacing in the `component.html`

```
<option  *ngFor="let c of filter.ListPricelist[selectedPriceListIndex]?.currencies" [ngValue]="c.id" selected="selected">{{c.code}}</option>
```

By the following :

```
<option  *ngFor="let c of filter.ListPricelist[registerForm.value.pricelist-1]?.currencies"  [value]="c.id">{{c.code}}</option>
```

Comment: Try: <option [ngValue]="null">Select a currency</option>

Comment: Still renders as a blank :/

Comment: have you tried with <option selected>Select a currency</option> ?

Comment: just do `this.registerForm.updateValueAndValidity()`, You just have to re validate your form.Depending on how complex the form is, you may have to re-validate a specific control. Or run that function after you init the new component

Comment: @kushalshah Yes I tried it, my bad for not precising it, sorry

Comment: @O.MeeKoh I tried both running it after init and right after I set up the post request but it still render as a blank tho

Comment: Try running it on the specific controls. like `this.registerForm.controls['pricelist'].updateValueAndValidity()`

Comment: @O.MeeKoh No changes, it really won't render it

Comment: i just noticed, youre using `[ngValue]` i always use `[value]`

Comment: @O.MeeKoh Still a blank.. Thank's alot for trying tho, I'll update the post if I find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace .setValue to .patchValue like Down

```
  pageChanged(event){
const current = this.currentPage = event;
return this.httpClient.get<QuotationsInterface>(`this.url${this.projectId}?page=${current}&token=${this.token.token}`)
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log('GET PROJECT BY ID OK',data);
      this.project = data.project;
      this.registerForm.patchValue({
        pricelist:  this.project.pricelist_id,
        currency:   this.project.currency_id
      });
    },
    error => {
      console.log("PAGE PROJECT FAILED", error)
    }
  )
```

}

Comment: **.patchValue** doesn't work in my case I think, just tried it and it still renders as a blank

Answer (score 0):

You can just bind default value in select portion and pass which value you want to show as a default one.
for eg.

```
<select name="bindDefault" [(ngModel)]="bindedValue"> </select>
```

and you can pass value to bindedValue from ts as a default one.

[demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7dzrkh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I can't use **ngModel** since I'm already using **Reactive Forms**